# How may I match a number with the number stored in contact list?

Tags: android, android-contacts, telephonymanager

I want to match a number in the contactlist
i got the contactlist in my activity i tried to match the contactlist with a number that is stored in contactlist but i am not getting the result as per....
The code that i have used is...

```
    String phoneNumber = null;

            Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

            String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;

            String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;

            String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

            Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;

            String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;

            String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;


            String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;

            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

            Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                    null);

            // Loop for every contact in the phone

            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                    String contact_id = cursor
                            .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));

                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));

                    int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

                    if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                        //output.append("\n First Name:" + name);

                        // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact

                        Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                                PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                new String[] { contact_id }, null);

                        while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//i am getting the incoming call number here, the toast is displayed
        //String number="+919729226730";                    
                            phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                            .getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                    if(number.equals(phoneNumber)){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("phone", "number matched");
                    }



                    output.append("\n Phone number:" + phoneNumber);
                        }

                        phoneCursor.close();




                    }

                    output.append("\n");

                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the order

change this:

```
if(number.equals(phoneNumber)){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Log.i("phone", "number matched");
 }


 phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
          .getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
```

to

```
 phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                            .getColumnIndex(NUMBER));

if(number.equals(phoneNumber)){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     Log.i("phone", "number matched");
}
```

Get the `phoneNumber` first and then compare.

Comment: but its not working in the case of incoming call...i got the incoming call number and i saved that in number variable but i am not getting that toast ...Could you please tell sir whats the reason behind this...????

Comment: Log.e the number that you are getting it could be that the number has - or space in it and hence it doesnt match with whats in the db ?? Where in the code have you initialized number ??

Comment: it is the same number +919729226730

Comment: i displayed the toast for the incoming call number and it is the same that i stored in my contactlist

Comment: when an incoming call is detected, you might want to store the number in a shared preference and then fetch the number from there, since an incomin call detection can take place inside a receiver. Accessing the variable from there might not work

Comment: i sent the number from receiver class to service class and this whole code i wrote in service class

Comment: did u put the phonenumber = code on top of the if ? is there a second number option for the same ???

Comment: iv not worked much with contact and contact uri, so i was asking is this calling number a second number of the user? But then when you declare number inside the while block it works, otherwise it doesnt correct ?

Comment: try comparing it with the second number ?? i mean if the db content uri allows u to get the second number ?

Comment: i was making a silly mistake the number was saved with 0 not with +91 and may i know what must i do that it must also check if the number is saved with 0 or without 0 and +91

Comment: may be you could get the first digit and check if its a 0, if yes, replace it with +91.. but i am not sure how well this might work :)